# Is it possible to list friends in facebook Feed Dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In a Facebook feed dialog is it possible to post a feed that lists friends that will get listed in the the post to the wall like

"...with Friend1, Friend1 at some place"

For instance in the this link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

it shows an image "Post to Your Wall", can I also get it to list friends?

Is this possible or do I have to use Open graph or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use Open Graph for this.
Simply use the **Feed Dialog** with params:

```
tags: USER_ID1, USER_ID2,
place: 107905939237016
```

The feed will be posted like:

> "...with Friend1, Friend1 at some place"

Comment: tags and place does not seem to be supported.

Comment: Well it does. Why don't you give a try?

Comment: I did but it does not show up. You can see from the docs that it's not supported
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: I know that it's not mentioned in the docs, but it works and I am using this in many applications.

Comment: use `me/feed` with `tags: VALID_USER_ID` and `place: VALID_PLACE_ID(say 109530785744253)`

Comment: How do you determine the user IDs of the friends that you would like to tag?